# PyTorch set_grad_enabled(False) vs with no_grad():

Tags: pytorch

Assuming autograd is on (as it is by default), is there any difference (besides  indent) between doing:

```
with torch.no_grad():
    <code>
```

and

```
torch.set_grad_enabled(False)
<code>
torch.set_grad_enabled(True)
```

Comment: Related: [Save and restore autograd enabled state](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53447406/5353461)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Actually no, there no difference in the way used in the question. When you take a look at the source code of `no_grad`. You see that it is actually using `torch.set_grad_enabled` to archive this behaviour:

```py
class no_grad(object):
    r"""Context-manager that disabled gradient calculation.

    Disabling gradient calculation is useful for inference, when you are sure
    that you will not call :meth:`Tensor.backward()`. It will reduce memory
    consumption for computations that would otherwise have `requires_grad=True`.
    In this mode, the result of every computation will have
    `requires_grad=False`, even when the inputs have `requires_grad=True`.

    Also functions as a decorator.


    Example::

        >>> x = torch.tensor([1], requires_grad=True)
        >>> with torch.no_grad():
        ...   y = x * 2
        >>> y.requires_grad
        False
        >>> @torch.no_grad()
        ... def doubler(x):
        ...     return x * 2
        >>> z = doubler(x)
        >>> z.requires_grad
        False
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.prev = torch.is_grad_enabled()

    def __enter__(self):
        torch._C.set_grad_enabled(False)

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        torch.set_grad_enabled(self.prev)
        return False

    def __call__(self, func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def decorate_no_grad(*args, **kwargs):
            with self:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return decorate_no_grad
```

However there is an additional functionality of `torch.set_grad_enabled`  over `torch.no_grad` when used in a `with`-statement which lets you control to switch on or off gradient computation:

```py
    >>> x = torch.tensor([1], requires_grad=True)
    >>> is_train = False
    >>> with torch.set_grad_enabled(is_train):
    ...   y = x * 2
    >>> y.requires_grad
```

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/autograd/grad_mode.html

---

Edit:

@TomHale Regarding your comment. I just made a short test with PyTorch 1.0 and it turned out that the gradient will be active:

```
import torch
w = torch.rand(5, requires_grad=True)
print('Grad Before:', w.grad)
torch.set_grad_enabled(False)
with torch.enable_grad():
    scalar = w.sum()
    scalar.backward()
    # Gradient tracking will be enabled here.
torch.set_grad_enabled(True)

print('Grad After:', w.grad)
```

Output:

```
Grad Before: None
Grad After: tensor([1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
```

So gradients will be computed in this setting.

The other setting you posted in your answer also yields to the same result:

```
import torch
w = torch.rand(5, requires_grad=True)
print('Grad Before:', w.grad)
with torch.no_grad():
    with torch.enable_grad():
        # Gradient tracking IS enabled here.
        scalar = w.sum()
        scalar.backward()

print('Grad After:', w.grad)
```

Output:

```
Grad Before: None
Grad After: tensor([1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
```

Comment: I believe I found a difference in my answer below. But it could be just the documentation not matching the code. I'd appreciate your review.

Comment: Cheers for the code showing the issue. Seems like a doco issue. Issue raised [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/19189).

Answer (score 2):

The [`torch.autograd.enable_grad` documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#torch.autograd.enable_grad) says:

> Enables gradient calculation inside a `no_grad` context. This has no effect outside of `no_grad`.

Given this wording, the following is expected:

```
torch.set_grad_enabled(False)
with torch.enable_grad:
    # Gradient tracking will NOT be enabled here.
torch.set_grad_enabled(True)
```

vs:

```
with torch.no_grad():
    with torch.enable_grad:
        # Gradient tracking IS enabled here.
```

But as [blue-phoenix shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53447634/5353461), this is **not** the case.

I raised an issue [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/19189).

Comment: Hey @TomHale, thanks for your comment. Please check my edit, I just made a quick test and it seems they both versions are equivalent in this regard. So gradients will also be enabled in your first setting.