# Save and restore autograd enabled state

Tags: pytorch

Is there a way of saving and restoring the current state of autograd?

eg:

```
saved_state = torch.autograd.get_grad_enabled()  # How do I do this?
torch.autograd.set_grad_enabled(temporary_state)
# do things for great justice
torch.autograd.set_grad_enabled(saved_state)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Source code for `torch.autograd.grad_mode`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/autograd/grad_mode.html) hints at a solution:

```
torch.is_grad_enabled()
```

It seems that [this function is currently undocumented](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/4474#issuecomment-441245282).